# how to Find the port number according to PID

Tags: linux, process, netstat, port, ss

The following command can be used to find out which process is listening on a particular port:

```
netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':8011'
```

How can we do the opposite, find the port number according to PID number?

Comment: Perhaps `netstat -ltnp | grep 'PIDNUMBER/'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lsof` is more appropriate for this:

```
sudo lsof -i -a -p PID
```

replacing `PID` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

According to *netstat* manual :

> This program is mostly obsolete.  Replacement for netstat is ss.

So let's use [ss](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) with its -p option then pipe to grep the desired pid.